# Preview not loading on keypress

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am new to jQuery.

I have created something like when I click the `add` button show the textarea and I enter data in textarea that want to show preview.

but preview is not working

http://jsfiddle.net/nGfh4/

HTML:

```
<div id='TextBoxesGroup'>
    <div id="TextBoxDiv1">
        <label>Textbox #1 :</label>
        <input type='textbox' id='textbox1'>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="add_comment_box"></div>
<input type='button' value='Add Button' id='addButton'>
<input type='button' value='Cancel Button' id='canButton'>
```

JavaScript:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    var commentNode = $('#lp-comment');
    //$(' #live-preview-form textarea').bind('blur keyup',function()
    commentNode.keypress(function (event) {
        alert('test');;
        commentNode.text($('#comment').val());
        commentNode.html($('#lp-comment').html().replace(/\n/g, '<br />'));
    });

    $("#addButton").click(function () {

        // $('#add_comment_box').css('display','block');
        var newTextBoxDiv = $(document.createElement('div')).attr("id", 'form').hide();
        //   newTextBoxDiv.after().html('<label>Textbox # : </label> <input type="text" name="textbox" id="textbox" value="" >');
        newTextBoxDiv.after().html(
            '<div id="live-preview-form" class="lp-block">' +
            '<textarea name="comment" id="comment" class="input" rows="10"></textarea>' +
            '</div>' +
            '<div id="live-preview-display" class="lp-block">' +
            '<div id="lp-comment">' +
            '</div>');
        newTextBoxDiv.appendTo("#add_comment_box").slideDown();
        //   $("#TextBoxesGroup").append(newTextBoxDiv);
    });

    $("#canButton").click(function () {

        $('#form').slideUp(function () {
            $('#form').remove();
        });
        return false;
    });
});
```

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/nGfh4/ see this link

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Could you be a bit more specific with your question? The more specific you are, the easier it is for us to help you!

Comment: @crynix jsfiddle.net/nGfh4  see this link

Comment: @Malai: Code is hardly enough to explain what you are trying to do or what the problem is. You say *"preview is not working"* but **what does that mean**? Is the preview not showing? Does it not look like you expected it to look? If so, how do you expect it to look? Do you get any errors? Please be more specific. And your fiddle is not working at all because it does not find jQuery... how do you expect us to help you?

Comment: @FelixKling i mean when click addButton that time one text area will show..... if i enter the value in textarea i want to see preview   http://jsfiddle.net/nGfh4/

Comment: Yes, I already know that. I asked you to be specific about *what does not work*, for example: *"I expect the preview to have a blue border but it is black"* or *"If I type '\*foo\*', I expect to see 'foo' in bold in the preview, but it is not bold"* or *"If I type any characters, the preview should appear but it does appear at all*".

Comment: @Malai: You don't want the event to occur on key press but on key up. Show your hidden preview text box on `$("id of the preview box").keyup(function(){ //Here the code to show preview })` Use [this](http://api.jquery.com/keyup/)

Comment: Your fiddle throws the error `ReferenceError: $ is not defined`, it does not work at all. Why are you including an ancient jQuery version in the body instead of selecting one of the newer jQuery versions in the selectbox?

Comment: So problem with the broken fiddle is that we don't know if your problem is the reference error or whether it is something else.

Comment: @Fleix Kling i dont know what type of error.....  if i type in text area i want to see preview

Comment: @SilentAssassin onkeyup also not workig

Comment: @Malai What did you try ? Do you debug your JavaScript for errors using [Firebug](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/firebug/) ?

Answer (score 0):

See the demo on this [page](http://api.jquery.com/keyup/) at the bottom.

On typing something in the textbox besides "Type Something", a handler is triggered on **keyup** function. It also triggered on a button click event.

In the handler of **keyup** function you can write the logic to display the preview.